# how can I pull the navbar on left side and fixed on it using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

hello there I want to try on this like the gallery button and user side dropdown on the left side and its not show on mobile mode when the screen minimize but show on the top like ackta ltd the complete code is on snippet but i try many time to do but its can't solved to me please  help me in this query if you people want pic i will upload the pic for you but i think the snippet code is enough for you pepole

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap All in One Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/headerstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbarCollapse");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "display";
  }
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>Ackta LTD UK</b></a>
    <button  type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" id="navbarCollapse"  onclick="myFunction()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link " href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</a>
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> About</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="privacypolicy.php">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="termofuse.php">Terms & Use</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="team.php">Teams</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block ">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
          <div class=" container pr-5  ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block "><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gallery</button>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item dropdown pr-5">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle user-action"><img src="assets/i/face.png" class="avatar" alt="Avatar"> Paula Wilson <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Profile</a></a>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Calendar</a></a>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i> Settings</a></a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8AC;</i> Logout</a></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to implement that kind of logic yourself - how & when to collapse on mobile is already built into Bootstrap, so just play around with their [various examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) and make sure to switch to mobile view while doing so.

Comment: you will open the snippet on full screen and check i want that the gallery and user profile is not show on small screen

Comment: If you want certain parts of your screen to be shown or hidden depending on screen resolution, you'll want to read about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Bootstrap has them, [too](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/).